# Steam Engine Question

Tags: etymology

I'm in a play "Around the World in 80 Days" and need help with some steam engine lingo.  I need to know the difference between 'short steam' and 'all steam.' Here's the line from my script to give some context:

"Sir, since we started, we have kept up hot fires in all our furnaces.  We had enough coal to go on short steam from New York to Bordeaux, but we don't have enough to go with all steam from New York to Liverpool."

Comment: I've not been able to find support for this, but I believe that it is possible to adjust the 'cut-off' {of steam to the cylinders) earlier or later during the expansion stroke; a longer cut-off generates more power / speed but obviously uses up the steam (and thus fuel) more quickly.

Comment: [Enginemanwook](https://enginemanwook.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/steam-engine-steam-cutoff-explained/) has an article that at least explains the 'variable cutoff' principle for power vs efficiency (though for steam locomotives).

Comment: Is there a possibility that the ship is a hybrid sail/steam? The term short-steam then reflects sail augmented by steam power and all steam means no sail as a helper? This would clarify the idea that there was not enough coal to make a full steam journey as the distances to either port are similar.  Prevailing winds and/or currents may also be a factor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a technical question, not one about the English language.

Comment: I'd suggest engineering.SE but I don't know how many historical mechanical engineers hang out over there.

Comment: @Icy, if I recall correctly, the ship in "Around the World in 80 Days" is a hybrid. They end up running before a westerly gale that shreds the sails, and then they burn the now useless mast and spars (and the furniture) as fuel in order to steam into Liverpool on time ... or something like that.

Comment: I’m sure that the “short” in *short steam* is the same “short” that’s in *short sail* where they would “reef” the sails to expose a smaller sail area to the wind.  The obvious term when steam came on the scene for not running at full capacity would be “short steam” and under *short steam* one would obviously use less fuel.  I assume they achieved *short steam* as @EdwinAshworth suggests by controlling the volume of steam allowed into the cylinders using the cut-off controls.

Comment: Would be best to find some sort of railfan chart site.  Apparently SE doesn't have one, though.

Comment: @Jim - https://books.google.com/books?id=OpVGAx4YqloC&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=%22short+steam%22+train&source=bl&ots=Fep_-Ls53n&sig=b5cvMt5wM-AHUVZyYK_NfF94E0s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj61J3nhIzWAhXpq1QKHerdBeAQ6AEISDAK#v=onepage&q=%22short%20steam%22%20train&f=false

Comment: @HotLicks - I think that’s different.  That refers to the length of the locomotive.

Comment: @HotLicks - https://books.google.com/books?id=0FAZAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=%E2%80%9Cshort+steam%E2%80%9D+%E2%80%9Cshort+sail%E2%80%9D+alabama&source=bl&ots=3ppurdwArU&sig=ycdEiQvCgXOWljORaMkX2EnOx8g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN3vyjhozWAhVLiFQKHV4tD5oQ6AEIMTAK